# Add Image on Gmail URL Scheme

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, gmail, url-scheme

```
guard
    let subjectEncoded = subject.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed),
    let bodyEncoded = body.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
else { return nil }

let image = screenshot.image
let gmailURL = URL(string: "googlegmail://co?to=\(to)&subject=\(subjectEncoded)&body=\(bodyEncoded)")
```

I'm using this to send email via Gmail and it works but I can't find how to add image in body or as attachment.

Is it possible to do this with an `UIImage` or `Data`?